# How to lock screen orientation to landscape for Android?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, cordova, screen-orientation

There are lots of similar questions on stackoverflow and I have tried multiple ways but nothing is working for me. I am doing a Sencha application using phone gap. i want show the app only in Landscape mode.

I have followed the link below to create Sencha touch2 - Phonegap appplication
http://vimeo.com/55335529.
I have tried the following :

a. Inside the manifest file(FirstApp\build\FirstApp\android\AndroidManifest.xml) i have added the line `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` but when i do Sencha build then the complete app is building and thus the above line is missing.

b. I have added this line 
`< preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />` inside the res/config.xml
still same. It doesnt lock the orientation.

Can anyone please help me in resolving this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you build your cordova app ( e.g. using cordova as cordova build android ) and that is done after building the sencha app, then just before deploying it to device ( using cordova run android ), in cordovaProject/platforms/android/AndroidManifest , u can add this

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

It works for me.